# Correct Dielectric Height on Differential Impedance Calculation?

Tags: usb, differential, rp2040

I'm designing a custom PCB around the Raspberry Pi RP2040 MCU. Their hardware design guideline said the traces between the USB and the termination resistors should have a **differential impedance of 90 ohms**.

Using an [online differential impedance calculator](https://resources.altium.com/p/differential-microstrip-impedance-calculator), the height of the dielectric layer, *h*, is needed. If [JLCPCB's 4-layer PCB](https://cart.jlcpcb.com/impedance) is used and the two inner layers are set as GND planes only, *h* would be the distance between the traces on the top plane and the closest inner ground plane. **Thus *h* =  ~0.2mm. Am I correct?**

JLCPCB 4-Layer Stack up Info:
[image: JLCPCB 4-Layer Stack]

Online Altium Differential Impedance Calculations:
[image: Altium Differential Impedance Calculator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. If you are using a 4-layer stackup and the two inner layers are ground planes, then you will have microstrip routing on your top and bottom layers.

So the spacing between your inner reference layer and your signal is given by the thickness of the material (prepreg) between the top/bottom layer and the closest inner layer, which is 0.2mm.